# D3.Js Bar Chart issue

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to draw Bar Chart using D3.js but not successfully.
I am trying as follow

**Model.cs**
    public class BarChart
    {
        public DateTime TaskDate { get; set; }
        public float Duration { get; set; }
    }

**Index.cshtml**
In my Index.cshtml (razor syntax, mvc view)
I have following code to draw bar chart

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title> Report</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https:/Scripts/d3pie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https:/Scripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
    .axis path, .axis line
    {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #777;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .axis text
    {
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size: 13px;
    }
    .tick
    {
    stroke-dasharray: 1, 2;
    }
    .bar
    {
    fill: FireBrick;
    }
</head>
```

Bar Chart java script

```
<svg id="visualisation" width="1000" height="500"></svg>

<script>
    var jsonData  = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.BarChart));


    data = jsonData;

    InitChart();

    function InitChart() {

        var barData = data;

        var vis = d3.select('#visualisation'),
          WIDTH = 1000,
          HEIGHT = 500,
          MARGINS = {
              top: 20,
              right: 20,
              bottom: 20,
              left: 50
          },
          xRange = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right], 0.1).domain(barData.map(function (d) {
              return d.Date;
          })),


          yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([0,
            d3.max(barData, function (d) {
                return d.Duration;
            })
          ]),

          xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(xRange)
            .tickSize(5)
            .tickSubdivide(true),

          yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(yRange)
            .tickSize(5)
            .orient("left")
            .tickSubdivide(true);


        vis.append('svg:g')
          .attr('class', 'x axis')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ')')
          .call(xAxis);

        vis.append('svg:g')
          .attr('class', 'y axis')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (MARGINS.left) + ',0)')
          .call(yAxis);

        vis.selectAll('rect')
          .data(barData)
          .enter()
          .append('rect')
          .attr('x', function (d) {
              return xRange(d.Date);
          })
          .attr('y', function (d) {
              return yRange(d.Duration);
          })
          .attr('width', xRange.rangeBand())
          .attr('height', function (d) {
              return ((HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) - yRange(d.Duration));
          })
          .attr('fill', 'grey')
          .on('mouseover', function (d) {
              d3.select(this)
                .attr('fill', 'blue');
          })
          .on('mouseout', function (d) {
              d3.select(this)
                .attr('fill', 'grey');
          });

    }
</script>
```

I am getting error in Console

```
Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute height="NaN"
Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute y="NaN"
```

Comment: Have you checked what `yRange(d.y)` is returning? I have a pretty good guess...

Comment: How does your data get the y-values? It seems to me that those are missing.

Comment: I just updated my code yRange(d.Duration) and xRange(d.Date) but still getting the error Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute height="NaN"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess.

Try changing all `d.y` to `d.duration` (or `d.Duration`) and make your model an array of values.

Your d3 code is based on the idea that `data` aka `barData` aka `jsonData` is an array. Which is not the case in your current code.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Koz58SZJ1C9hS2rDmBSj?p=preview

Comment: Console view shows var jsonData  = [{"Date":"\/TaskDate(1429041600000)\/","Duration":2.15,,"Date":"15-Apr-2015"}];

Comment: What does `yRange(...)` return?

Comment: That seems odd. Because it should return 20. Given that your range is [480,20] and domain [0,2.15].

Comment: I can see y-axis and x-axis on view but at the same time i can see string ".axis path, .axis line { fill: none; stroke: #777; shape-rendering: crispEdges; } .axis text { font-family: 'Arial'; font-size: 13px; } .tick { stroke-dasharray: 1, 2; } .bar { fill: FireBrick; }" on view and in console the error is .axis path, .axis line { fill: none; stroke: #777; shape-rendering: crispEdges; } .axis text { font-family: 'Arial'; font-size: 13px; } .tick { stroke-dasharray: 1, 2; } .bar { fill: FireBrick; }

Comment: I re-updated my code "return ((HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) - yRange(d.Duration));" now i can see both y-axis and x-axis.  Y-axis range is 0-2 and x-axis is current date.

Comment: I think it is fine? What you say Rouby?

Comment: That should be correct. Are you still getting the error?

Comment: No Error it seems fine. But how i can hande array? I don't think so this will work if my data object has more than one element (e.g. more than one date). How can i iterate and assign x-axis and y-axis? Any idea/hint Rouby?

Comment: This will work fine with multiple dates.. just make sure your jsonData is an array. D3 will take care of it ;) I have updated my answer with a working plunker with your code and multiple values.